# String to Table passing two delimiters split in ssrs reports

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

Need to display string data to table using ssrs reports.
Have data in new_details field as string format

`PO SEQ Country
65774   1   PE
27039   1   PA
27040   1   PA
27041   1   PA
27042   1   PA
27043   1   PA
27044   1   PA
27045   1   PA`

need to convert as this data into table. i tried below query but it not worked.

```
declare @ModelID VARCHAR(max)

--make sure to use brackets
set @ModelID = (select new_details from new_order
where newid='857647')

select @ModelID

DECLARE @p VARCHAR(50)
select * from dbo.SplitStringtoTable(@ModelID,'  ')
```

Now getting output as

```
Item
PO
SEQ
Country  65774
1
PE  27039
1
PA  27040
1
PA  27041
1
PA  27042
1
PA  27043
1
PA  27044
1
PA  27045
1
PA

Need to split data based on tab space"  " for next column and double tab space"     " for next row.
```

Required as table in ssrs reports.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you want to split  string into multiple columns, right? If so, I think you could try to use query like below to achieve goal

```
DECLARE @Tmp TABLE (Id INT,Name VARCHAR(20)) 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 1,'Vidhyasagar,K' 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 2,'Sathya,S' 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 3,'Madhu,K' 


--Using PARSENAME 

SELECT Id, 
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,',','.'),2) Name, 
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,',','.'),1) Surname 
FROM @Tmp
```

You could refer to [T-SQL Script to Split a column with delimited string into multiple columns](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/T-SQL-Script-to-Split-a-308206f3) for details.

Zoe